# oracle Find one or more values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to find if a customer that's still a client (client= has one or more account opened, `'O'`, even if they have closed account `'C'`)

If they have all the accounts closed, it's not any more client). So I have 2 tables, one with the customers and one with the accounts. How to join it or make select in select to do it correctly?

```
CUSTOMER_NO| FULL_NAME| ACC_ISOPEN| COUNT(ACC_ISOPEN)
0114115| DAESCU ANCUTA-IOANA|   C|  2
0114115| DAESCU ANCUTA-IOANA|   O|  2
0141677| LINCAN CLAUDIA|    C|  2
0141677| LINCAN CLAUDIA|    O|  8
0149469| VOICU ANDRE GEORGE|    O|  2
0158605| CSORTAN BARNA| C|  15
```

So, first 3 persons are clients but the last has just closed accounts which means isn't any more an active client.

How to do it?

Customer table

```
CUSTOMER_NO FULL_NAME
0114115 DAESCU ANCUTA-IOANA
0141677 LINCAN CLAUDIA
0149469 VOICU ANDRE GEORGE
0158605 CSORTAN BARNA
```

Account table

```
CUSTOMER_NO ACCOUNT_NO  ACC_ISOPEN
0114115 B13RONECON011411501 C
0114115 005EURP77Z011411501 C
0114115 005EURCRT0011411501 O
0114115 005RONCRT0011411501 O
0141677 008RONP09L014167701 O
0141677 008EURP111014167701 O
0141677 008RONP06L014167702 O
0141677 008USDCRT0014167701 O
0141677 008EURCRT0014167701 O
0141677 008RONP111014167701 O
0141677 008EURP03L014167701 O
0141677 008RONCRT0014167701 O
0141677 008RONP111014167702 C
0141677 008RONP06L014167701 C
0149469 058RONCRT0014946901 O
0149469 058EURCRT0014946901 O
0158605 008RON001L015860503 C
0158605 008RON0111015860503 C
0158605 008RON0111015860501 C
0158605 008RONP111015860502 C
0158605 A08RONECON015860501 C
0158605 008RON0111015860502 C
0158605 008RONP210015860501 C
0158605 008RONP09L015860501 C
0158605 008RON0210015860501 C
0158605 008RON012L015860502 C
0158605 008RON001L015860501 C
0158605 008RONP111015860501 C
0158605 008RON001L015860502 C
0158605 008RON012L015860501 C
0158605 008RON006L015860501 C
```

Comment: I want to make a select in wich I show the name, customer_no and 'Y' if it's a client and 'N' if it's not...

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it with a single table scan for each table:

```
SELECT c.CUSTOMER_NO,
       MAX( c.FULL_NAME ) AS FULL_NAME,
       a.ACC_ISOPEN,
       COUNT( 1 ) As num_accounts
FROM   Customers c
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT a.*,
                COUNT( CASE acc_isopen WHEN 'O' THEN 1 END )
                  OVER ( PARTITION BY customer_no ) AS num_open
         FROM   accounts a
       ) a
       ON (   c.customer_no = a.customer_no
          AND a.num_open    > 0 )
GROUP BY
       c.CUSTOMER_NO,
       a.ACC_ISOPEN
```

> I want to make a select in wich I show the name, customer_no and 'Y' if it's a client and 'N' if it's not...

```
SELECT c.CUSTOMER_NO,
       MAX( c.FULL_NAME ) AS FULL_NAME,
       CASE
         WHEN COUNT( CASE acc_isopen WHEN 'O' THEN 1 END ) > 0
         THEN 'Y'
         ELSE 'N'
       END AS has_open_account
FROM   Customers c
       INNER JOIN accounts a
       ON (   c.customer_no = a.customer_no )
GROUP BY
       c.CUSTOMER_NO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.customer_no, y.full_name, x.acc_isopen,
                COUNT (DECODE (acc_isopen, 'O', 1, 0)) 
                OVER (PARTITION BY x.customer_no, y.full_name ORDER BY x.acc_isopen) cnt
           FROM ACCOUNT_TABLE x JOIN CUSTOMER_TABLE y ON (x.customer_no = y.customer_no)
          WHERE acc_isopen <> 'C'
```

Comment: This will get one row per account, instead of grouping it as per the OP's expected output, and will also return customers who have no open accounts.

Comment: Thanx for pointing that out. I had misunderstood the question. I thought the first data set was the desired output. Modified my query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe will be not the best way to write a query , but understandble :

```
select c.FULL_NAME , 'Y'
     from CUSTOMERS c 
      where c.CUSTOMER_NO in (select distinct CUSTOMER_NO
                    from ACCOUNTS 
                   where ACC_ISOPEN = 'O')
     -- the query above returns all the customers with at least one open account
     union 
     select c.FULL_NAME , 'N'
     from 
     CUSTOMERS c 
     where c.CUSTOMER_NO in 
                (   select CUSTOMER_NO from CUSTOMERS 
                    --here from all customers with are putting out from the result all customers with at least one open account (we return customers with no open account)
                     minus 
                    (select distinct CUSTOMER_NO
                    from ACCOUNTS 
                   where ACC_ISOPEN = 'O') 
                );
```

Comment: This will not get the count of the number of open/closed accounts as per the OP's expected output.

Comment: @Ady Lacan wrote :  
I want to make a select in wich I show the name, customer_no and 'Y' if it's a client and 'N' if it's not... –